# MySql query to return avg number od chapters by book per months

Tags: php, mysql

I would appreciate your help greatly,I'm using php and mysql and I'm getting some unrealistic results, can you check my code if it is alright...btw the tables involved are

**BOOKS**

```
id, book_title, isbn, publisher, price, l1_subject_id, l2_subject_id, 
description1, description2, description3, call_date, chapter_proposal_date,
notification_acceptance_date, publishing_fee_date, final_manuscript_date,
1st_proof_reading, 2nd_proof_reading, book_schedule_date, active, url, 
pages_num, edited_by, downloaded_num, file_size, unix_name, voted, 
general_notes, BMcomment, description4, about_the_book, call_started, 
kw_mandatory, kw_other, ignore_small, show_contributing_authors
```

**BOOKS_CHAPTERS**

```
id, users_id, books_id, order, books_sections_id, manuscript_title, price, 
active, paypending, notice, created_at, last_modified, keywords, status,
book_editor_comments, hard_copy, invoiceing_data, extended_deadline, 
next_deadline, technical_notice, number
```

---

```
 SELECT 
COUNT(b.book_title) as `Total number of books `, 
COUNT(bc.manuscript_title) as ` Total number of chapters`, 
#DATE_FORMAT(b.call_started, '%M %Y') as `Date`, 
#DATE_FORMAT(b.call_started, '%Y-%m') as `Original date format`,
(COUNT(b.book_title)/COUNT(bc.manuscript_title)) as `Average chapter number by book per      
month`,
b.id as book_id
FROM books b
JOIN books_chapters bc ON (b.id = bc.books_id)
WHERE b.call_started IS NOT NULL AND b.call_started != '0000-00-00'
#GROUP BY MONTH(b.call_started), YEAR(b.call_started),b.id
#ORDER BY YEAR(b.call_started) ASC, MONTH(b.call_started)ASC
```

Comment: what unrealistic result are you getting?

Comment: So what you are getting ? What you want ?

Comment: What *exactly* is the issue here?

Comment: You're probably going to want to elaborate on exactly what results you're expecting, and what you're currently getting.

Comment: btw: posting the table fields is great. But it would be even better if you could post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE xyz` + some example records in the form of `INSERT INTO xyz ...` statements. Makes someone else testing the query a lot more likely ;-)

Comment: Posted the wrong code...sorry! I've just edited it...take a look now.

Comment: Honestly I think that I've done something wrong with left join and thats way I'm getting strange results

Comment: @ReneB Can you just edit out the details of the table structure that you don't want anyone to see, but leave only what's relevant to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join on chapters, but you count on book titles.
That means that you count the title for each chapter in the total number of books (or per month, if you re-add the group by).

Use `count(distict b.book_title)`, or rather `count(distinct b.id)` or `count(distinct b.isbn)` to get the number of distinct books in this result set.

Same goes for chapters, and there you should also use id, which is probably unique, auto-numbered. Chapter titles may be the same between books.

Comment: Worked like a charm! thank you! love for stack overflow it's a noobs dream!